# Where can I generate OPLS AA parameter for KOH and NaOH

Tags: lammps

I am running LAMMPS simulation where KOH and NaOH  are being utilized. I was successful in finding pair coefficients from literature but could not get hold of bond coefficients(kr & r theta)for KOH and NaOH. Lipargen server however works only for organic ligands.
I am unable to complete my topology file for LAMMPS simulation since I am failing to obtain bond coefficients of O-H bond of KOH and NaOH.
Can anyone please help me.
Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Why would you want KOH and NaOH to be bonded? Assuming that you are studying a solution, the ions would become solvated, meaning that there is no bond between the cation and anion.

Comment: I am trying to bond NaOH and KOH differently, not together.

Comment: I understood that. My question is slightly different. When NaOH Or KOH is introduced into the solution, the ions will become solvated, meaning that there is no longer any bond between the cation and anion

Comment: Yes indeed they will solvate but I must provide initial values(starting points) for MD simulation

Comment: I agree that you will need to provide initial coordinates and FF parameters for the simulation. What I am trying to say is that you most likely **will not** get a bond coefficient for Na and OH or K and OH, because they are not parameterized as NaOH and KOH, but instead as Na+, K+ and OH-.